# Многопоточность и swing

Tags: java, многопоточность, swing

Есть простой интерфейс, при нажатии кнопки запускается процесс обработки загруженных данных.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    ReaderAllFiles rw = new ReaderAllFiles();
    rw.process(Constatns.PATH);
    ...
}
```

как запустить этот же метод rw.process(Constatns.PATH) с помощью многопоточности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class SomeTask extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
    private final ReaderAllFiles rw;
    private final String path;

    public SomeTask(String path) {
        rw = new ReaderAllFiles();
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        rw.process(path);
        return null;
    }
}

task = new SomeTask(Constatns.PATH);

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: а что метод doInBackground() должен вернуть?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.